# How can I retrieve same text values on a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I retrieve the same date values on this table using javascript or jQuery?
I need to manipulate it in a way that I can have all information with the same date compiled together without repeating the date.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89BET/1/)

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>10/19/2013</td>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>3 Margueritas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10/19/2013</td>
        <td>Mary Jane</td>
        <td>2 Sodas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10/25/2013</td>
        <td>Paul Stanley</td>
        <td>1 Cold Gin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10/25/2013</td>
        <td>Jenny Johnson</td>
        <td>2 Cosmopolitans</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10/25/2013</td>
        <td>Francis Patton</td>
        <td>10 Beers</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>01/06/2013</td>
        <td>Taylor Dalton</td>
        <td>4 Tequila Shots</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: are dates already sorted? And is all you want not to display unique date more than once?

Comment: I am assuming you want to group data using a hierarchical table structure?

Comment: Yes, using a hiearchical table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumes dates in order

```
var dates = [];
$('#myTable tr').find('td:eq(0)').text(function (i, date) {
    var exists = $.inArray(date, dates) > -1;
    if (!exists) dates.push(date);
    return exists ? '' : date;
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v7DLu/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they're already sorted, you can just iterate through the dates and remove ones whose previous date is the same.

```
var dates = $('td:first-child');
for (var i = 1; i < dates.length; i++) {
    if ($(dates[i]).html() == $(dates[i - 1]).html()) {
        $(dates[i]).html('');
    }
}
```